# Manusear objeto somente em métodos

Tags: java, classes, método

Quando eu crio uma instância de uma classe eu consigo acessar seus atributos somente quando estou dentro de um método, porque? No exemplo abaixo eu consigo dar um `set` no método `main()` mas não dentro da classe, por que?

```
public class App {

    Pessoa p = new Pessoa();
    p.

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("teste");
        Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();
        pessoa.setNome("Teste");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classes são estruturas de dados, elas servem apenas para declarar o que deve ter nessa estrutura, ela não pode ter algoritmos (mandar fazer), o lugar de algoritmos é o método. Classes não garantem ordem de execução, métodos sim, é uma linha atrás da outra, toda manipulação de dados tem que estar no método. Na verdade nem vejo sentido em fazer algo fora deles, se você acha que tem algum motivo deveria justificar isso.

Claro que alguma linguagem pode permitir algo do gênero de forma limitada (no fundo só seria *syntax sugar*, ainda teria a execução em um método mesmo que de forma disfarçada, C# faz muito isso, mas apenas para inicializar um valor em um campo ou propriedade declarada), mas precisaria ter uma motivação, não pode ser só porque alguém quer, ou porque é bonitinha, tudo o que uma linguagem permite gera um custo para ela, uma obrigação que ela sempre terá que carregar para sempre.

O termo atributo aí foi usado equivocadamente, queria dizer membros. Mas o problema nem é acessar o membro e sim fazer um processamento, e acessar um membro seria uma forma de processamento. Nem vou falar que o que aprendeu que chama [atributo na verdade se chama campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101).

Comment: Não que veja sentido, é só pra tirar a dúvida mesmo.

Comment: Existe um campo de execução garantida que é indicado por um bloco `{..}` sem identificador, executado ao criar o objeto (semelhante ao que `static { ...}`  faz para classes). É bom como um adendo de construtores para garantir algum estado interno que precisa ser criado de maneira não trivial.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado que é um método, ele só não tem nome (internamente tem).